# Correctly open and close multiple windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a Windows Forms application that is using multiple forms.  The program first runs the form with a login screen that allows the user to select a specific profile with their settings, and there's a button that opens another form to create a new profile.

The code I'm using looks like this

```
Form2 secondform = new Form2();

private void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    secondform.Show();
}
```

When I try to use

```
this.Close();
```

instead of

```
this.Hide();
```

The entire application exits, even if I put it after showing the new form.

The problem is that once you've entered the main program, the only way to shut down the program entirely is to click the exit button I've put on there, which uses

```
Application.Exit();
```

If you try to right click on the taskbar icon and close from there, or use the red exit button, the process still runs, and has to be terminated from the Task Manager.

What can I do so the application closes correctly?

Comment: The form that you try to close is the first one opened by your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the main entry point of your WinForm application, i.e. the static **Main**  method of the "Program.cs" file, show the login form as a modal dialog there and then call the **Application.Run()** method with an instance of your main form. Here's a simple example:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Show the login form
        LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
        loginForm.ShowDialog();

        // Show the main form
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
}

class LoginForm : Form
{
    public LoginForm()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Blue;
        Text = "Login Form";
    }
}

class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        BackColor = Color.Red;
        Text = "Main Form";
    }
}
```

The code above will first show a dummy login form (in blue) and when it's closed, the main form (in red) will be shown. The code is pretty straightforward, no need of hiding and special closing of forms and so on.

Comment: Aha!  Awesome, I knew there was some way to do this correctly.  Thanks, the form.ShowDialog(); was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try is this:

```
private void aButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    secondform.Show();
    secondform.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(sf_FormClosed);
}
void sf_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form.closing event on your form with the exit button. Then use application.close(). 
You can also den a reference of your login form to the form it opens ( you may need to do this anyways for other reasons ) you can then use a global and store the login form in that. Then do loginForm.close() to exit the application.